# How to unzip a file to a target folder using 7-zip

Tags: batch-file

So I know I can unzip a .zip file using

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e *.zip
```

but how do I do it so that I can choose which folder it will unzip it to?

Comment: I suggest you double click on help file `7zip.chm` stored in the program files folder of 7-Zip and __read__ the chapter __Command Line Version__. Everything you asked and which was gently answered by [Adit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5125261/adit) is documented in help of 7-Zip. For example command `x` is better than `e` if the archive files contains also folders and not just files. The help can be also opened directly from within GUI version of 7-Zip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -oc:\path\to\directory *.zip
```

Comment: Could you do me a favor and explain what the e and -o do? I think -o means override, and e means extract?

Comment: The 'e' command is for extracting files from an archive. The 'o' switch is for setting the output directory.

Comment: How would I get it to overwrite?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -oc:\path\to\directory -y *.zip`

Answer (score 2):

example:

`'"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x *.zip -oc:\path\to\directory -aoa'`

flags `-aoa` are used to override the files.